# Create jstree hierarchy from parent child pair from table

Tags: python, json, django, recursion, jstree

I have a parent child pair from table,
example:

```
links=(("Tom","Dick"),
       ("Dick","Harry"),
       ("Tom","Larry"),
       ("Bob","Leroy"),
       ("Bob","Earl"),
       ("Earl","Joy"), 
       ("Joy","Joy child"), 
       ("Joy","Joy child2"),
       ("Joy child2", "Maria"))
```

and I am trying to create jstree from this pairs. I went through various links but cant get this tuple to work. Can anyone please provide a recursive function in python which takes the tuple as mentioned above or any combination of parent-child-grand-child pairs as input and creates a hierarchy by creating a json similar to  this format

```
{
     "name": "Tom",
     "children": [
         {
             "name": "Dick"
         }
     ] 
}
```

Thank you in Advance:) I really appreciate your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [how to ask a good question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @agold I tried this link functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025130/recursively-build-hierarchical-json-tree-in-python

Comment: What is wrong with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18025360/1771479)?

Comment: @agold , When I executed the function in second  answer, it only generates first level parent child nodes and the other pairs are not seen in the json. Also, the correct answer does not give all the parent child nodes in the json.

Comment: @agold, Its my bad, yes the function in the link is working fine. Thank you for your help. I am closing this story now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18025130/recursively-build-hierarchical-json-tree-in-python

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

links = (("Tom","Dick"),("Dick","Harry"),("Tom","Larry"),("Tom","Hurbert"),("Tom","Neil"),("Bob","Leroy"),("Bob","Earl"),("Tom","Reginald"))

name_to_node = {}
root = {'name': 'Root', 'children': []}
for parent, child in links:
    parent_node = name_to_node.get(parent)
    if not parent_node:
        name_to_node[parent] = parent_node = {'name': parent}
        root['children'].append(parent_node)
    name_to_node[child] = child_node = {'name': child}
    parent_node.setdefault('children', []).append(child_node)

print json.dumps(root, indent=4)
```